# Is it possible to generate one half of a Karman Vortex Street?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, vortex

The [Karman Vortex Street](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A1rm%C3%A1n_vortex_street) is a type of phenomenon which is generally illustrated by examples in which a long, solid, smooth circular cylinder moves at constant velocity through a fluid. The long axis of the cylinder is perpendicular to the relative velocity vector. Eddies form on the downstream side of the cylinder and detach at a regular temporal rate. The eddies form alternately in two places either side of the "flow axis".  The downstream wake behind the cylinder can be described as a series of alternating, counter-rotating vortices.  Karman vortex streets can also be generated by cylinders with other cross-sections, even by flat plates.

**My Question**

Is it possible to generate a "vortex street" which consists of a single series of co-rotating vortices?

**Example**

Consider an infinitely wide river with a flat bottom and water flowing steadily from west to east and a solid, smooth cylinder with semi-circular x-section attached (curved surface upwards) to the riverbed  with its long axis running north-south. Now is it possible, under certain combinations of fluid viscosity, fluid velocity and cylinder geometry, that, on the downstream side of the cylinder, tubular vortices parallel to the cylinder will periodically form, grow and detach and be carried downstream at regular time intervals?

Comment: Don't [airfoils do what you want](http://weblab.open.ac.uk/firstflight/images/vortex/vortex_formation.gif)? Or am I misunderstanding your goal?

Comment: @KyleKanos. No that is not what I am thinking of.  I have revised my example to try and make it clearer what I  seek.

Comment: This might be the case of breaking out your trustiest CFD program and looking at a few different Reynold's numbers.

Comment: @KyleKanos. Good suggestion, but getting into CFD would be a major project for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. 
These kind of corotating Karman Vortex Streets do exist.
[image]

I have made real video's about this, when I noticed it in nature. No CFD, but Real stuff.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iXfkaFmpnL4&list=PLgUc9kJnDMMExJivT2dWh9dAjdYYUgOFE&index=8

I was studying Turbulence, and I am more interested in other aspects of this flow. (Optics)

But in the video you could see how this single vortexes or creating this "half street", they are same times divided to smaller ones and united to a single one. But anyhow, clearly only another half of the typical vortex street.

It should be noted that all Vortexes are "single vortexes". [I actually have even better example of this kind of Vortex](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UnRXXhXFkU8&index=6&list=PL489087BF3C5D6131). You can actually found [this patented dropstructure](http://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/biblio?DB=worldwide.espacenet.com&II=0&ND=3&adjacent=true&locale=en_EP&FT=D&date=20130919&CC=WO&NR=2013134886A1&KC=A1), which energy dissipation is based on such a one half vortex street.

[image]

So it's basically a open channel nozzle. **At this case the one-sided rotation becomes very apparently, as there is a strong continuous counter-current at the riverbanks.** 
You can see some of the [benefits of the structure live here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qv-SXXiexh0&list=PL489087BF3C5D6131&index=2)

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Yes thankyou. It appears to be what I was asking for - a single series of co-rotating vortices. Although I cannot be 100% sure from the video that all the vortices are rotating the same way (clockwise). Also there is a separate but perhaps complimentary series of vortices, less well-defined, flowing from the other side of the red-daubed rock (at top of the screen).

Comment: You can find more videos in my channel, and see even really clean one; <https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hiye-tTpibw&index=4&list=PLgUc9kJnDMMExJivT2dWh9dAjdYYUgOFE> here every single big vortex rotates to same direction. It's not just so easy to see, cause there is no color, and the youtube video quality is so low.

Comment: @JokelaTurbine - Mainly for interest. I took 4th photo  from top of page [**here**](http://azatlasz.hu/2014/07/kina_vietnam_konfliktus) in 2009 and it is now in dozens of places on the web (no credit, no $ :-) ). THere seem to be vortex streets off a number of the islands and the rear ones appear closer to linear that double sided. Probably not the case but appearance is interesting.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon - I see trails of cumulus clouds (presumably) downwind of islands (above which I presume ascending thermal air pockets have produced the clouds).  This is interesting (to me) in its own right but I don't see von Karman vortices :-).

Comment: @steveOw I also :-). BUT do you see more than that, or not?  .... 
[**HERE is a larger version**](http://g2.img-dpreview.com/842F2F82B79242DA9AA6D54121446FDE.jpg) The cloud streams correlate with island positions. In some cases it is hard to see anything that unquestionably shows the characteristic vortex street appearance but there seem to be asymmetrical left-right-left patterms in each case BUT I may be seeing "Martian Canals" where there are none :-). At bottom centre you have a series of "puffs". Given the very flat nature of the islands, and vortex action around the low lying ground ....

Comment: .... is going to mix with the "straight over the top" wind and destroy the pattern reasonably well. Interestingly6, island at bottom right seems to generate nothing - maybe too uniformly low?
Comments welcome.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon there is definetly a "Street" at the small Island nearest the observer. Most probably the reason is the bay; there is two "bumbs" which results the visible vortex. The reason why the big island bottom right doesn't generate, might be the humidity. There are vortexes, but you just don't see them. But they suck some moist, and so after the second "bumb" & "suck" they become visible.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon + JokelaTurbine. I see island at left of bottom centre does have a cloud trail which may be a von Karman like pattern but I can't be sure as we are not looking down on it from above.  Also, if the island was causing such a pattern I would expect the vortices to be bigger.  Perhaps the two parts of the island are producing alternate thermal bubbles?

Comment: @steveOw I am in no way expert in such things so cannot comment definitively. But JokelaTurbine says " ... there is definetly a "Street" at the small Island nearest the observer ...". Based on the content of his answer I'd expect him (her) to "know their stuff". Maybe not. I have done some prior looking at these effects generally with a view to possible application in a quite different area and I'd not be surprised if all the cloud trails visible were vortex street associated but also very disturbed due to the low vertical heights of the obstructions allowing direct through flow to interact.

Comment: @JokelaTurbine Nice dogs :-)